# Git commits not pushed

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-rewrite-history

I had a local repository cloned from a remote one. I made many commits from it but stupidly delete that repository without pushing back to the remote repository. I somehow managed to recover the directory. Now I am wondering whether the commits will also be recovered with the recovery or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't push your commits to remote repository and deleted local repository it means that you will not find this commits at repository anymore. If you have any backups it can help you. Other possible way - recover this files from the file system after deletion. It's complicated way and didn't guarantee the full recovery.

Comment: I have recover the repository, now whether the commits will be available or not. I re-installs git.

Comment: Recovered deleted repo? Check history, maybe your commits there. Or check `git reflog`

Comment: I pushed the repository to the remote one, all the changes were there, means the commits were also recovered with the local repository.